# Is it possible to develop fast, safe, streaming regex HTML minification?

Tags: html, regex, minify

I know, one should never parse HTML with regex. And parsing is the only way to get really effective HTML minification.

But what if I'm not that worried about perfection? I just want to get a reasonable amount of whitespace out of my HTML.

And instead of applying a regex to a massive file, I want to apply it to a stream of chunks of the file.

My current solution is simply this:

```
(?<=>)\s+(?=<)
```

That finds any places where there are more than one space between open and close HTML tags, e.g. `>   <`. I replace any matches with `" "` (a single space).

My questions are

1. Is this safe? i.e. is there anything in typical HTML that this might break?
2. Can I get better performance (speed and/or more matches) without sacrificing safety?

(P.S.: I've applied this to a file that was ~500kb. It went to 350kb. Using an external minifier took it to 340kb. I'm pretty happy with the 150kb savings and not too worried about the extra 10kb.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Consider this `HTML` snippet:

```
<div> 
    <p>Some paragraph here</p>
    <div data-rel="some data > < here"> 
        <p>some subparagraph here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here your expression matches the `> <` inside some potentially important data attribute as well (see [**a demo here**](https://regex101.com/r/EThjdC/1/)) - this might or might not break your code (ad 1.)

Concerning your second question (ad 2.), matching is usually faster then lookarounds, so you could as well write:

```
>\s+<
```

And replace this with

```
><
```

See the [**reduction in steps**](https://regex101.com/r/EThjdC/2) compared to your first expression here (259 vs 28 steps, a reduction by ~90 percent).

Comment: On a large file I saw 20x time savings. Thanks! Just a note, I'd replace with `> <` instead of `><` to handle `<strong>Don't smash</strong> <em>these together.</em>`.

Comment: How about `>\s{2,}<` replace with `> <` to account for `<strong>Don't smash</strong>[MULTIPLE SPACES]<em>these together.</em>`?

Comment: Sorry for the shouting, SO wasn't respecting the additional spaces.  :-P

Comment: @mac9416: It gets complicated very quickly when you're trying to formulate exceptions to the multiple spaces rule and regular expression might not be the proper way to handle these cases.

Comment: @mac9416: In addition to my last comment, see this [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/EThjdC/5) - it does what you want (ignoring your special cases) but is a crappy expression for a number of reasons - to have a finer control, I'd suggest using a parser.